# Frequency of a Relaxation Oscillator IC

Tags: integrated-circuit, oscillator, frequency, homework

How do I calculate the frequency of oscillation in this circuit?

I've gathered that I need to obtain the switch threasholds, which I thought I could do, but evidently I can't so a walk through on how to do that too would be great. From the examples in the book, it looks like a little estimation is allowed. The book seems to use Δt≈(CΔV)/(I)Δt≈(CΔV)/(I) and I≈15V/100k.

Any Help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Either you have the circuit complete with formulas to calculate the frequency and just take that for "the truth" **or** you want to confirm that by yourself (which is excellent) but then your first step is **understanding** the circuit. Understanding the switching threshold voltages is a crucial part of that. The switching occurs when the voltage on the + and - inputs are equal. If you know what the output voltages are at pin 7 (note that the output will be switching to minimum and maximum) then you can determine the voltage at the + input.

Comment: I'm not going to look up a 311, but does the output swing between GND and +15, or GND and something like +13? Having done that, what's the swing on the 311 +ve signal input, which you can do by resistor ratios? These are the threshhold voltages. Now the capacitor has to swing between these values, due to the current in the 100k, which is itself driven by the amplifier output. You now have enough information to figure it.

Answer (score 1):

- calculate the upper and lower switching threshold voltages that will be applied to -IN during charging and discharging cycles respectively. You can ignore the capcaitor and upper 100kΩ resistor for ths step. Just assume output high (high Z because it's an OC Output) and output low (-15V).
- calculate charge time during which \$V_C\$ is going from lower to upper threshold voltage and discharge time during which \$V_C\$ is going from upper to lower threshold voltage (the times are not exactly the same because equivalent series resistance of R network for charging is 104.7kΩ and for discharging it is 100kΩ). If you don't need high accuray (better than 5%) you can assume that both are about the same and half the calculation effort.

Get frequency as inverse of sum of charging and discharging time.

Answer (score 1):

With Emitter Pin 1 connected to Vee the output swing is ~ 30V.

Therefore from the Hysteresis 6.8k/106.8k * 30V = 1.91V

Ic=CdV/dt and with Voltage across the Cap, or **1/dt=Ic/(CdV)**
... dV = 1.91V differential or +/-0.95 wrt 0V
... **Ic=(Vcc-Vee + dV/2)/R**
... **dt=1/2f** , solve for f

Or an easier way if asymptote of T=RC=1e5*1e-8 = 1e-3 (1 ms)

... and 1.95V/30V ~ 6.5% so what is the time to ramp 1.95V? **0.065 ms**

so for two ramps f = 1/130us = 77 kHz